# APex-AWS callouts Exception:System.CalloutException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: apex, aws

Below code when i execting its gives Error

> Error: Exception USER:System.CalloutException: **Unexpected end of file from server**

Here Is code

```
String endpoint = bucketname+ '.' + host + '/' + filename;
               HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
               req.setMethod(method);
               req.setEndpoint('https://' + endpoint);
            req.setTimeout(120000);
               req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
               req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
               req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
               req.setHeader('Content-type', attach.ContentType);
               req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
               req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
               req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read');
            //req.setBody(attach.Body);
            req.setBodyAsBlob(attach.Body);

        String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' + attach.ContentType + '\n' + formattedDateString + '\n' +
            '/' + bucketname + '/' + fileName;

        String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
        Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), Blob.valueOf(secret));
        String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
        String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signed;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
        String decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encodedStringToSign , 'UTF-8');


            try {   
            Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + res.toString());
        System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());

        }catch(Exception e){ System.debug('Exception USER:'+e);   }
```

Comment: The receiving server has a firewall blocking the sf IP addresses.

Comment: @Rohit i got the problem and your solution but which IP Range can i set in my SF org

Comment: The issue is on server end so adding IP range in org won't solve your problem. Also I found in your code that `req.setHeader('Content-type', attach.ContentType);`  might cause this issue. Try setting it as `req.setHeader('content-type','application/json');`

Comment: @Rohit Still problem not solved

Comment: Check this [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132964/read-timed-out-unexpected-end-of-file-from-server-error/133022)

Comment: Still error coming @Rohit Mourya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54043/discussion-between-rohit-mourya-and-swapnil-udamale).